# UIViewController extension not recognized from another class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController+Scaling.swift` file, since the designs are fit to match a 414 pixel screen.

I have functions like

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    func wRatio() -> CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width / CGFloat(414.0)
    }
```

I confirmed the target for this extension is the same as my view controller.

but this function `wRatio` is not available in my view controllers. If I paste this extension code into that view controller, it is available.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly set the extension as `public` ? Otherwise try to clean your Derived Data, clean your projet and relaunch Xcode.

Comment: Are the view controllers Objective-C or are they swift too? If you use that function, what error do you get?

Comment: No dice with public . "Use of unresolved identifier `wRatio`